# How to find count of a string using regex in text file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, text-processing

I have a string in a text file. In text file, year should be in generic manner and I need to find count of string using regex expression

```
data here is  my text file 

sword="list of people  (2019) Revised 10"
count = data.count(sword)
print(count)
xtrct_data=sword.join(data.split(sword)[:count])
```

The  above one has worked. When I coded like this as I need in generic manner, it is not working.I used regular expressions.

```
my code:

sword=re.search("list\sof\speople\s\([0-9]{4}\)\sRevised\s[0-9]+",data)
count=data.count(sword)
print(count)
```

My expected output should use regex **"list of people  (2019) Revised 10"** and I need count. Further to split based on occurrence.

expected output:
If **"list of people  (2019) Revised 10"** the word was 10 times in a text file it should return 10

Comment: What is your actual expected output?

Comment: @Tim Biegeleisen Just the count of a string using regex

Comment: So you want the number of times `list of people (2019) Revised 10` appears in the text?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen yes, year 2019 and revised 10 may change according to the year and revised version

Comment: Can you give an example?

Comment: Please re-read my first comment.

Comment: I want to make sure if revised word also changes or only the number beside that

Comment: No revised word doesn't change only number @ KiranMayee Maddi

Answer (score 0):

Check this:

```
import regex as re
data = 'list of people  (2019) Revised 10 list of people  (2018) Revised 9 list of people  (2017) Revised 8'
regex = ur"list of people (.*?) Revised (.*?)"
print(len(re.findall(regex, data)))
```

The above code will count the occurrence even if the year and the number after the revised word changes.

Hope this helps!